# what is wrong in this func php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wrote this function in PHP in order to query a DB, if I manually type the staff_ID 04033 in the query as follow it work perfectly...

```
function getReportByID(PDO $pdo){
    $query = "SELECT users.staff_ID, users.Name, reports.id_report_show, reports.date_report 
                FROM `users`
                    JOIN reports ON reports.staff_ID = users.staff_ID
                where users.staff_ID = 04033";
    
    $st = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $st->execute();
    $result = $st->fetchAll();
    
    
    if (count($result) == 0) {
       print_r('no result');
    } else {
    
      print_r($result);
    } 

}
```

but if I use the variable $staff_ID in the query it does not find anything.

```
function getReportByID(int $staff_ID, PDO $pdo){
    $query = "SELECT users.staff_ID, users.Name, reports.id_report_show, reports.date_report 
                FROM `users`
                    JOIN reports ON reports.staff_ID = users.staff_ID
                where users.staff_ID = $staff_ID";

    $st = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $st->execute();
    $result = $st->fetchAll();
    
    
    if (count($result) == 0) {
       print_r('no result');
    } else {
    
      print_r($result);
    } 

}

getReportByID(04033,$pdo);
```

what i'm doing wrong? (really a beginner in PHP and sql)

thanks

Comment: Use {$staff_ID} instead of $staff_ID.

Comment: @Trukken That makes no difference.

Comment: Why not use a prepared statement for this, instead of an SQL query that is vulnerable for SQL injection?

Comment: Afterall you ARE running a Prepare anyway

Comment: @deceze Makes the code that much easier to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PHP, 04033 is in octal (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

That means this:

```
getReportByID(04033,$pdo);
```

Is actually passing this decimal value:

```
getReportByID(2075,$pdo);
```

But in MySQL, numeric literals with a leading zero are not interpreted as octal numbers. So 04033 is just decimal 4033. That's why it works when you put the number in your SQL query literally.

---

Solution: Use strings, not integers. And please use query parameters to prevent a SQL injection vulnerability.

```
function getReportByID($staff_ID, PDO $pdo){
    $query = "SELECT users.staff_ID, users.Name, reports.id_report_show, reports.date_report 
                FROM `users`
                    JOIN reports ON reports.staff_ID = users.staff_ID
                where users.staff_ID = ?";

    $st = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $st->execute( [ $staff_ID ] );
    $result = $st->fetchAll();
    
    
    if (count($result) == 0) {
       print_r('no result');
    } else {
    
      print_r($result);
    } 

}

getReportByID("04033",$pdo);
```

Comment: So is there any possible solution ? Since my staff_ID in MySQL table are are all number like 04033/04650 or similar.. how could I write the function in order to dynamically change the staff_id?

Answer (score -3):

Read about how to properly concatenate strings. Try this way:

$query = "SELECT users.staff_ID, users.Name, reports.id_report_show, reports.date_report FROM `users`JOIN reports ON reports.staff_ID = users.staff_ID  where users.staff_ID = " . $staff_ID;

And do not forget to quote/sanitize your strings, especially when the values are comng from user input.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. An SQL query should never be built like that